# Reading value from TAR register in MSP430

Tags: embedded, msp430

How should i go about reading value from TAR register in msp430. I wnat to see the values, like we have serial monitor to do so in Arduino. I know we do not have anything like that in msp(except energia of course).I am coding in CCS 5.5.0.

Comment: Sir,energia is just like your arduino's IDE where the coding of your micro-controller can be done in a pretty easy way and is a nice tool whch can be used by the beginners to get their hands dirty with programming micro-controller without having much knowledge of embedded C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registers for the MSP430 processors are defined in standard headers and can then just be accessed as variables, they are just memory locations after all.  There is a gotcha with the TAR and TBR registers in that they can sometimes return an intermediate value if they are in the process of being updated as a clock count increments the register contents so I have always used the following code to guard against this problem.

```
uint16_t   Timer_Value ;

Timer_Value = TAR ;
while ( Timer_Value != TAR )
{
    Timer_Value = TAR ;
}
```